# Django send key or value from the view to the form class

Tags: django

I am writing an Edit form, where some fields already contain data. Example:

```
class EditForm(forms.Form):
    name = forms.CharField(label='Name', 
                           widget=forms.TextInput(), 
                           initial=Client.objects.get(pk=??????)) #how to get the id?
```

What I did for another form was the following (which does not work for the case of the previous EditForm):

```
class AddressForm(forms.Form):
    address = forms.CharField(...)

    def set_id(self, c_id):
        self.c_id = c_id

    def clean_address(self):
        # i am able to use self.c_id here
```

## views.py

```
form = AddressForm()
form.set_id(request.user.get_profile().id) # which works in the case of AddressForm
```

So what is the best way to pass an id or a value to the form, and that could be used in all forms for that session/user?
Second: is it right to use initial to fill in the form field the way I am trying to do it?

Answer (score 0):

You need to override the `__init__` method for your form, like so:

```
def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
    try:
        profile = kwargs.pop('profile')
    except KeyError:
        super(SelectForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        return
    super(SelectForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
    self.fields['people'].queryset = profile.people().order_by('name')
```

and, obviously, build your form passing the right parameter when needed :)